# CodeIgniter form_radio always save first element

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have this code to save form_radio function

```
$reference_note = array('Room' => 'Room', 'Room 1' => 'Room 1', 'Room 2' => 'Room 2', 'Room 3' => 'Room 3');
             //echo form_dropdown('reference_note', $reference_note, '', 'class="form-control input-tip" id="reference_note"'); 
           foreach ($reference_note as $key => $value) {
               echo form_radio('reference_note',$key,false, 'id="reference_note"').$value;
           }
```

It's taking first element from array (Room)

Thanks

Comment: be more specific pls ! As long as i check its working well ! not only in html but also showing correct data on from submit as like array(3) { ["reference_note"]=> string(6) "Room 1" ["name"]=> string(3) "fgh" ["description"]=> string(3) "fgh" }
             array(3) { ["reference_note"]=> string(6) "Room 3" ["name"]=> string(3) "fgh" ["description"]=> string(3) "fgh" }

Comment: Sure, showing fine html; but when click in radio button save first array position (Room) in Database

Comment: Here is Code gist if somebody wants to share your answers: https://gist.github.com/c3media/2279b54fcac9745d148e0a55c8d77e83/revisions

Answer (score 0):

hello @c3media i checked again for u and it was perfect. on submit when i get the result in php its showing correct value each time . are you geting form value in php or javascript or jquery ? and one thing is sure because all of your radio elements id is same so if u try to get the value by id it will show you the first one may be ! so you have to put unique  id for each element or you can use class and then get the checked ones value by javascript or jquery ! i am giving you my test form to check !

```
 <?php
   print_r($_POST);
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    <script  src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/jquery.js'; ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
        <form method="post" action="" name="stackForm">
            <?php $reference_note = array('Mesa' => 'Mesa', 'Mesa 1' => 'Mesa 1', 'Mesa 2' => 'Mesa 2', 'Mesa 3' => 'Mesa 3');
            $i = 0;
                   foreach ($reference_note as $key => $value) {
                       echo form_radio('reference_note',$key,false, 'id="reference_note'.$i.'" class="reference_note"').$value;
                       $i++;
                   }
                   ?>
               <button type="submit">go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            $(document).on('change','.reference_note',function(){
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```